# Issues with ports on OpenShift DIY server trying to run Mirth Connect

Tags: openshift, mirth, openshift-cartridge

I'm trying to setup a Mirth Connect (https://www.mirth.com/) instance on a DIY server on OpenShift for a course I'm giving.

Mirth Connect needs two ports, HTTP and HTTPS, 8080 and 8443 by default.

It seems I can configure 8080 or 8443, but not both, and Mirht seems to use both. It uses 8080 to let me download a Java Webstart app that is used for administration, but that apps fails to load some resources from the server, when tries to use 8443.

I raised an issue in the Mirth JIRA, but I'm not sure this is an issue on Mirth itself or some misconfiguration on the OpenShift side. Here is that issue: http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/issues/browse/MIRTH-3948

Any ideas of what can be wrong with OpenShift?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already looked at [exposing services](https://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#exposing-services-tcp-endpoints)?

Comment: No I didn't, at a glance it seems that is for cartridges, but I didn't build have a cartridge or know where to locate that manifest file. Any pointers?